# unable to generate fault type while calling java axis webservice

Tags: asp.net, webservices-client

Hi my sincere thanks to techies,

let me explain what im facing issue.

iam calling axis java webservice from vs 2010

if iam trying to call the service direclty using [.wsdl] link using soap ui and in .net add ref im getting errors.

now i was generated the wsdl file and type1.xsd and fault.xsd from java tools.

if im using these .wsdl phycal file ,im unable to get the **fault.xsd,** or fault type

and in proxy the fault class is not created.

can you help where im doing wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call Axis Service from .net client, use `wsdl.exe` from visual studio command prompt to generate proxy or use `Service Reference`. That will make your task easy